# Login and reggistration on wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

[Login and registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLAXg.png)

With a wordpress plugin, I already have the login and registration. After hitting the submit button, it is not redirected to the next page, but instead redirects to the same page.

```
<?php if ($facebook_enabled ) : ?>
    <div class="social_connect_ui <?php if( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) echo 'mu_signup'; ?>">
        <p class="comment-form-social-connect">
        <?php if( $display_label !== false ) : ?>
            <label><?php _e( 'Connect with', 'social_connect' ); ?></label>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="social_connect_form">

            <?php if( $facebook_enabled ) :
                echo apply_filters('social_connect_login_facebook','<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Facebook" class="social_connect_login_facebook"><img alt="Facebook" src="'.$images_url.'facebook_32.png" /></a>');
            endif; ?>

        </div></p>



        <?php
        session_start();
        include_once 'dbconnect.php';

        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
        {
            header("Location: home.php");
        }

        if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
        {
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
            $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

            if($row['password']==md5($upass))
            {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
                header("Location: home.php");
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
                <?php
            }

        }
        ?>
        <html>
        <div id="login-form1">
        <form method="post">
        <table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><button type="submit" name="btn-login">Sign In</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="register.php">Sign Up Here</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
        </html>
```

Comment: Uh, could you clarify your issue? I don't understand what you mean by "how to direct this on the index page having the logout button"

Comment: After signing on the forms and hitting the submit button, it actually redirects me to the same page having the password, name,sign up here...

try it here http://robswym80.eighty.axc.nl/news1/
having this credentials
email: sample1@yahoo.com
password: qwertyuiop

@Epodax

Comment: I wan it on the same page having the logout button on the widget side.....

Comment: Use WordPress built-in [functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) to check for pass and login.